# Change placeholder of input when I select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying out some jQuery coding but doesn't seem to work. In the `#vat` input, I need the placeholder to change.

```
    <select id="VatExpense">
        <option value="" disabled selected></option>
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1"></option>
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1"></option>
    </select>

   <input type="text" id="vat" placeholder="Rate">
```

Comment: where is the problem? Also the value property should be unique!
But if the text property is not important, then you can do it like this.

Comment: Where is the _trying out some jQuery coding_ code?

Comment: I need the #vat input placeholder to change when I select an option. When I select an option with value=0, the placeholder of #vat should change to 20%, and if it's value=1, to 0% @Legends

Comment: do you want to do it with native js or do you have jQuery at your hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `data-` attributes, not `value` to determine the rates.

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnfsmile/t8gqy8c7/1/)

HTML:

```
<select id="VatExpense">
    <option data-rate="20" value="" disabled selected>Expense Type</option>
    <option data-rate="20" value="0">Telephone</option>
    <option data-rate="0" value="1">Public Transport & Taxis</option>
    <option data-rate="20" value="2">Computer Consumables</option>
    <option data-rate="20" value="3">Subsistence</option>
    <option data-rate="0" value="4">Overseas Travel</option>
</select>
```

Then read them in the jQuery and change the placeholder accordingly.

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
      $("#VatExpense").change(function(){
         $("#vat").attr("placeholder", $(this).find(":selected").data("rate") + "%");
      });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Jquery :

```
$("#VatExpense").on("change", function() {
    var vatExpense = $("#VatExpense option:selected").val();
    var vatPlaceholder = "Rate";
    if (vatExpense == 0) {
        vatPlaceholder = "Standard rate 20%";
    } else if (vatExpense == 1) {
        vatPlaceholder = "Zero Rate 0%";
    }
    $("#vat").attr("placeholder", vatPlaceholder);
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/kzmL0e1j/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
(function() {
    var placeholders = {
        'value_':'Rate',
        'value_0':'Standard rate 20%',
        'value_1':'Zero Rate 0%'
    };
    $("#VatExpense").on('change', function(e) {   
       $("#vat").prop('placeholder', placeholders['value_' + $(this).val() ]);        
    });
})();
```

Comment: I think this is a place to prefer [`attr` over `prop`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr). Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try below like this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6x1q6hje/) use `attr()`

```
$('#VatExpense').change(function(){    
var selectedval = $(this).val();    
if(selectedval == 0){
  $('#vat').attr('placeholder','Standard rate 20%');
}else if(selectedval == 1){
 $('#vat').attr('placeholder','Zero Rate 0%');
}    
});
```